# Django Rest Framework: POST and PUT in a single nested request

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework to create an object. The JSON contains nested objects as well; an array of objects to create and link to the "main object" and an object that should be partially updated.

JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "opcitem_set" : [
    {
      "comment" : "Test comment",
      "grade" : "1",
      "name" : "1a"
    },
    {
      "comment" : "Test comment",
      "grade" : "2",
      "name" : "1b"
    },
    {
      "description" : "Additional test item",
      "comment" : "Additional comment",
      "grade" : "1",
      "name" : "extra_1"
    }
  ],
  "is_right_seat_training" : false,
  "checked_as" : "FC",
  "date" : "2015-10-23",
  "check_reason" : "Check ride",
  "opc_program" : "2",
  "is_pc" : true,
  "questionnaire_test_passed" : "Passed",
  "pnf_time" : 2,
  "other_comments_complete_crew" : "Other comments",
  "other_comments_flying_pilot" : "Other comments",
  "is_cat_2_training" : false,
  "opc_passed" : "Passed",
  "pilot" : {
    "pc_valid_to" : "2015-10-23",
    "id" : 721,
    "email" : "jens.nilsson@nextjet.se",
    "total_time" : 3120,
    "medical_valid_to" : "2015-10-23"
  },
  "pf_time" : 2,
  "aircraft_type" : "S340",
  "typeratingexaminer" : 734
}
```

The "opcitem_set" contains objects of type OpcItem that should be created and have a ForeignKey to the main object. So far so good, I can do this by overriding the create() method on the ModelSerializer as outlined in http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations.

Then we have the case of the "pilot" object. This will always contain an ID and some other fields to PATCH the object with that ID.

The "typeratingexaminer" field is just another "Pilot" object, but it shouldn't be PATCHed, just set as a foreign key.

My question is: Can I PATCH (partially update) the "pilot" as well in the create() method, or would that break some sort of design pattern? Since it's really a PATCH and not a POST, should I do it in a separate request after the original request has finished? In that case, can I have a transaction spanning two requests, so that if the second request fail, the first request will be rolled back?

Would love to be able to send only one request from the client instead of splitting it in two requests. Maybe you could separate the JSON already in the ViewSet and send it to different serializers?

Happy to hear your thoughts about this, I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would recommend to move away from the serializer create method and build your extensive logic in the view, where you could make good use of simpler, dumb serializers where needed. You could surly do updates in the create method of your serializer but suddenly that's not a serializer anymore, it's more of a controller, thus it would be better placed in the view code, by overwriting the create or post method; this design enables you to have only one request from the client, you can massage the request data in the view code and use simple serializers to instantiate/update objects, with embedded data validation, if needed.

If you have models and serializers you could share, we might be able to comment more to the point.

Comment: This sounds like the best way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not creating a main object but only nested objects you should override .update() method in the serializer and do somethink like this:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):

    if 'opcitem_set' in validated_data:
        opcitem_set_data = validated_data.pop('opcitem_set')

    if 'pilot' in validated_data:
        pilot_data = validated_data.pop('pilot')

    ...

    for opcitem_set in opcitem_set_data:
        Opcitem.objects.create(main_object=instance,
                               **opcitem_set)

    current_pilot = self.instance.pilot
    current_pilot.pc_valid_to = pilot_data.get('name', current_pilot.pc_valid_to)
    ...
    current_pilot.save()

    """
    Update instance as well if you need
    """

    return instance
```

If you need to create main object as well then you need to override .create() method. But then PATCHing `pilot` will be not really a good way to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do have a main object though, so I'll go for creating the logic in the view and using different model serializers instead.